# replacing the positive and negative number of a column with certain condition

Tags: awk

I have a text file that contain four columns of numbers.

I want to keep or modify the 4th column based on the following rules:

- if it falls within the range of `-2.100552742679913983e-02` to `-1.249582196275393240e-02` - `no change`
- if it falls within the range of `1.381056887718538353e-04` to `2.346095085764924595e-04` - `no change`
- if negative - generate a new random number within the range of `-1.8445493471994996071e-03` to `-1.145493471994996071e-03`
- if positive - generate a new random number within the range of `1.531056887718538353e-06` to `1.956056887718538353e-06`

Sample input:

```
$ cat input
> > >   
2.60000038 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.249582196275393240e-02
2.70000076 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.296202816069126129e-02
2.80000114 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.527230263998111234e-02
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.100552742679913983e-02
> > >
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.150552742679913983e-01
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -2.190552742679913983e-01
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000  -2.190552742679913983e-03
> > > 
0.500000000 2.99699998 -1.14950405E-09 1.381056887718538353e-04
0.600000381 2.99699998 -1.66670497E-10 2.346095085764924595e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-04
0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.126244050537546566e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.136244050537546566e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-03
> > >
```

Example replacements for negative numbers:

```
# from

2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.150552742679913983e-01
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -2.190552742679913983e-01
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000  -2.190552742679913983e-03

# to

2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.149552522674912181e-03
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -1.141552612675913281e-03
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000  -1.346552142676911382e-03
```

Example replacements for positive numbers:

```
# from

0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.126244050537546566e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.136244050537546566e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-03

# to 

0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.561056887718538353e-06
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.621056887718538353e-06
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.506244050537546566e-06
```

Expected result for the entire set of input:

```
> > >
2.60000038 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.249582196275393240e-02        # no change
2.70000076 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.296202816069126129e-02        # no change
2.80000114 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.527230263998111234e-02        # no change
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.100552742679913983e-02        # no change
> > >
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.149552522674912181e-03        # new value
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -1.141552612675913281e-03        # new value
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000  -1.346552142676911382e-03        # new value
> > >
0.500000000 2.99699998 -1.14950405E-09 1.381056887718538353e-04    # no change
0.600000381 2.99699998 -1.66670497E-10 2.346095085764924595e-04    # no change
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-04    # no change
0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.561056887718538353e-06    # new value
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.621056887718538353e-06    # new value
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.506244050537546566e-06    # new value
> > >
```

**NOTE:** comments added for clarity

I tried :

```
awk '($4 >=-1.249582196275393240e-02  && $4 <= -2.100552742679913983e-02){print $1,$2,$3,$4}' input
awk '($4 >=1.381056887718538353e-04  && $4 <= 2.346095085764924595e-04){print $1,$2,$3,$4}' input
```

However, I do not know how to implement the rules for generating new random numbers. I hope experts may help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you tried has about nothing to do with your specifications. Why did you try this?

Comment: @chumunB: _ i am facing some problem_ : I have already seen more precisely asked questions than this ..... To be honest, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet sir just to replace...but i am new to shell scripting and awk, so facing problem,please help sir,

Comment: Thanks @user1934428, as i am new to awk and shell , i am not getting precise way to do it.if possible please help.

Comment: @chumunB : Then just ask a concrete question....

Comment: Edited it carefully, i hope its fine now???

Comment: @chumunB review the new edits to see if I misrepresented anything; I've flagged the question to be reopened based on the edits so we'll see how the others decide to vote; give this a couple hours and if it hasn't been reopened then consider copying to a new question (eg, `edit` this question, highlight the entire block of text, and cut-n-paste into a new question)

Comment: @markp-fuso unfortunately i cannot ask more question from this account as it shows
You have reached your question limit

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestions @markp-fuso

Comment: Why doesn't `-2.296202816069126129e-02` from line 2 get changed? It's not inside either of the ranges that you say should not be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OP's current code that tests for negative values in a range, the test values need to be switched (ie, `-2.100552742679913983e-02` is less than `-1.249582196275393240e-02`.

We can combine all of the tests and modifications into a single `awk` script:

```
awk -v seed="$RANDOM" '                                 # if available $SRANDOM should ensure more randomness
BEGIN { srand(seed)                                     # initiate awk random number generator

        # test ranges

        test_neg_min = -2.100552742679913983e-02
        test_neg_max = -1.249582196275393240e-02

        test_pos_min =  1.381056887718538353e-04
        test_pos_max =  2.346095085764924595e-04

        # new ranges

        new_neg_min = -1.8445493471994996071e-03
        new_neg_max = -1.145493471994996071e-03

        new_pos_min =  1.531056887718538353e-06
        new_pos_max =  1.956056887718538353e-06
      }

!/^>/ { # if line does not start with ">" the ...

        # if field #4 is negative and outside our test range, replace field #4 with a new negative random number

        if ( $4 < 0 && ! ( $4 >= test_neg_min && $4 <= test_neg_max ) )
           $4 = sprintf("%.18e", ( new_neg_min + rand() * ( new_neg_max - new_neg_min ) ) )

        # if field #4 is positive and outside our test range, replace field #4 with a new positive random number

        else
        if ( $4 >= 0 && ! ( $4 >= test_pos_min && $4 <= test_pos_max ) )
           $4 = sprintf("%.18e", ( new_pos_min + rand() * ( new_pos_max - new_pos_min ) ) )
      }
1                                                       # print current line
' input
```

This generates:

```
> > >
2.60000038 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.249582196275393240e-02
2.70000076 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.161336798144420573e-03
2.80000114 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.574493366149551160e-03
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -2.100552742679913983e-02
> > >
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.482455058873062602e-03
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -1.534007533960116132e-03
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000 -1.324348394828239262e-03
> > >
0.500000000 2.99699998 -1.14950405E-09 1.381056887718538353e-04
0.600000381 2.99699998 -1.66670497E-10 2.346095085764924595e-04
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-04
0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.947523358949625806e-06
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.612522816477175151e-06
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.780935388104584015e-06
> > >
```

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, however when my input is just little bit change, i.e. if i have  >>> symbol in between the rows randomly, does it work?

Comment: it gives answer but after >>> line it add some random number like          > > > -1.288267669309527564e-03

Comment: please update the question to show these new lines ... both in the sample inputs and the expected outputs

Comment: i updated the input file please have a look @markp-fuso

Comment: answer has been updated; fwiw ... as Ed's pointed out, some of the 'expected output' lines in the question appear to be incorrect, so my output also shows some lines changing when the 'expected output' shows they should not; for now I'm assuming this was a typo with the data originally placed into the question

Comment: Thank you very much @markp-fuso for your hard work,,you are really experts on progamming.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the numbers you're working with are too small for awk to be able to robustly compare them unless you use GNU awk built with MPFR for [Arbitrary Precision Arithemetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic). For example, you require awk to be able to test if a number like `-0.01249582196275393241` is less than or equal to `-0.01249582196275393240` - that's a comparison to 20 decimal points when I'm pretty sure the max precision that can be stored without MPFR is 17 and above about 15 you're already losing accuracy (e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568750/133219).

You need something like the following using GNU awk for [Arbitrary Precision Arithemetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    PREC = 50
    CONVFMT = OFMT = "%.18e"

    neg_acc_beg = -2.100552742679913983e-02
    neg_acc_end = -1.249582196275393240e-02
    pos_acc_beg =  1.381056887718538353e-04
    pos_acc_end =  2.346095085764924595e-04

    neg_chg_min = -1.8445493471994996071e-03
    neg_chg_max = -1.145493471994996071e-03
    pos_chg_min =  1.531056887718538353e-06
    pos_chg_max =  1.956056887718538353e-06

    if (seed == "") { srand()     }
    else            { srand(seed) }
}
!(      /^>/ ||
        ((neg_acc_beg <= $4) && ($4 <= neg_acc_end)) ||
        ((pos_acc_beg <= $4) && ($4 <= pos_acc_end)) \
 ) {
    if ( $4 < 0 ) {
        min = neg_chg_min
        max = neg_chg_max
    }
    else {
        min = pos_chg_min
        max = pos_chg_max
    }
    $4 = min + rand()*(max-min) " # random"
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -M -f tst.awk file
> > >
2.60000038 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.249582196275393240e-02
2.70000076 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.745496810369265642e-03 # random
2.80000114 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.573904107632305080e-03 # random
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.598592869722831322e-03 # random
> > >
2.89999962 2.99699998 -0.00000000 -1.800124621621710871e-03 # random
2.89999962 2.99699998 -5.00000000 -1.699769735752932817e-03 # random
2.89999962 2.99699998 -900000000 -1.342199391079360385e-03 # random
> > >
0.500000000 2.99699998 -1.14950405E-09 1.381056887718538353e-04
0.600000381 2.99699998 -1.66670497E-10 1.588483317773829457e-06 # random
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 2.136244050537546566e-04
0.800000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.891636587004151809e-06 # random
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.826667420598640320e-06 # random
0.700000763 2.99699998 -9.37441375E-11 1.616694144436782760e-06 # random
> > >
```

The "# random" text is obviously only there to highlight the changed lines, remove it when you're done testing.

It doesn't produce the expected output in your question because I don't understand the expected output in your question so you may have to debug it a bit but it shows you the idea and structure for such a script. In particular read up on Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic and how to set PREC in the gawk manual I referenced as it's not something I've used much and I'm not sure if 50 is a good value.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Numeric-Functions for more info on generating random numbers with `rand()` and `srand()`.

Comment: your random values are not as expected, the @markp-fuso output is fine...

Comment: Right, as I mentioned "It doesn't produce the expected output in your question because I don't understand the expected output in your question so you may have to debug it a bit". I don't think your expected output is correct as it looks wrong for some lines but I don't know all the ways in which it's wrong and you haven't replied to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372476/replacing-the-positive-and-negative-number-of-a-column-with-certain-condition/69393913?noredirect=1#comment122652750_69372476) about that so I'm not going to try to debug it.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, you need GNU awk with MPFR active for this to work reliably so if you're running any other awk or gawk without that then YMMV with whatever output you get.

Comment: Ok thanks @Ed Morton, i will try to debug it...

Comment: Step 1 would be to check that the expected output in your question is accurate and then either fix it if it's wrong or explain it if it's correct because both @markp-fuso and I have additional lines being identified as requiring changes from just the ones you indicated as such in your question.

Comment: Also something to consider in both answers you have so far is we're using `<=` and `>=` comparisons since that's what you asked for BUT the usual advice for floating point comparisons is to not try to check for equality so you should consider using slightly higher/lower range end points with  just `<` and `>` comparisons instead of `<=` and `>=`.